# three js get tangent/intersection of sphere and segment

Tags: three.js, geometry

I have `Vector3` **A** and `Vector3` **B**:

I need to know `Vector3` **C** (intersection of sphere and segment AB).

What is the best way to get this vector?

I need only one vector, no mater about precision or range.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pseudo-code

```
dAB[1] = B[1] - A[1]
dAB[2] = B[2] - A[2]
dAB[3] = B[3] - A[3]

rdAB = 1.0/sqrt(dAB[1]^2+dAB[2]^2+dAB[3]^2)

C[1] = A[1] + R*dAB[1]*rdAB
C[2] = A[2] + R*dAB[2]*rdAB
C[3] = A[3] + R*dAB[3]*rdAB
```

where `dAB` is a vector from `A` to `B`, `R` is a radius of the sphere, and `rdAB` is inverse length of the vector `dAB`.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent point C as a affine combination of point A and B as

C = (1-t)*A + t*B

then, the vector OC (where O is the center of the sphere) should have magnitude R (sphere's radius). From this you can obtain a quadratic equation of t and you can solve for t easily. Note that in general you should get two t values as the infinite line defined by A and B will intersect the sphere twice. So, you should only take the t value that is between 0 and 1. There will be cases where you only have one root (in fact duplicate roots) from the quadratic equation when line AB is tangent to the sphere and have no real root at all when line AB does not intersect the sphere.